# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `university.createIndex()` buffering timed out after 10000ms

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

When trying to go to HTTP://localhost/api/ this error occur and I get the data and when I remove universitymodel.createIndexes() it works how can i solve this error without removing createIndexes because I Need it while using $text search

**(node:34904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `university.createIndex()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
at Timeout. (S:\MyProjects\UniNotes\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:149:23)
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:557:17)

at processTimers (internal/timers.js:500:7)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:34904) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block,
or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:34904) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.**

> UniversitRoutes

```
import UniversityModel from "./../models/UniversityModel.js";

const router = express.Router();

router.get("/all", (req, res) => {
  UniversityModel.find({})
    .then((data) => {
      res.json(data);
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
});

export default router;
```

> index.js

```
app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use("/api", UniversityRoute);

connectDB();
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port ${5050}`.cyan);
});
```

> UniversityModel

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UniversitySchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
  },
  img: {
    type: String,
    require: true,
  },
  schools: {
    type: Array,
  },
  admins: [
    {
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      passwrord: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      permessions: [
        {
          type: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            required: true,
          },
          major: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            required: true,
          },
          school: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            required: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
});

UniversitySchema.index({ name: "text" });
const UniversityModel = mongoose.model(
  "university",
  UniversitySchema,
  "university"
);
UniversityModel.createIndexes();
export default UniversityModel;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the internet connection was bad and when I had changed the network it worked.